# I want to go back to the last activity before the app closed

Tags: java, android

I have 2 activities named ActivityOne and ActivityTwo. If I pressed the phone's home button at ActivityTwo, it will closed the app. So when if i run the app again, i want to go to the ActivityTwo where because it was the last activity before the application closed. To make it simple, I want to go back to the last activity before the application closed.

I didn't start any codes yet because i don't know how to start. I'm a beginner idol. I just created the two activities.

Comment: How do you start activity two from activity one? Please add the code. Normally it's a default behavior from android to return to the last activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like following

```
//step one
public class MySuperActivity extends Activity{
....
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {
            // step 2
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
....
}
//step 3
public class MainActivity extends MySuperActivity{
    @override
    public void onCreate(Bundle b){
          // check for stuff as you want to from step 3
    }
}
```

- step 1 : create your own Activity class by extending the Activity or ActionBarActivity or what ever you are using and that class will be something like this
- step 2 : for the second step you need to save your last used activity somewhere such as SQLlite or SharedPreferences or a file it's up to you
- step 3 : in your main activity (the one where the app starts) you need to detect the saved value from step 2 and go to that activity directly in the onCreateActivity method.

## alternative way

you can, of course, have another way which is replacing the step on by implementing the following code in every activity you have to avoid dealing with complex stuff in handling activities since you overrode the activity class.

your choice will depend on how much effort you want to put or how much you want to repeat code.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {
        // step 2
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```